# use Scala to get JSON data in lower levels

Tags: java, arrays, json, scala, json4s

I'm a beginner of Scala, and I have JSON data formatted like below:

```
{
    "index_key": {
        "time":"12938473",
        "event_detail": {
            "event_name":"click",
            "location":"US"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the content of "index_key" and **extract the content of second level as a new JSON objet** and initiate a class based on the second level data.

```
{
    "time":"12938473",
    "event_detail": {
        "event_name":"click",
        "location":"US"
    }
}
```

I tried to use **json4s** to extract from the above json to be a Event class, but how to get rid of the "index_key" which is the first level key?

```
 case class Detail(event_name: String, location: String)
 case class Event(time: String, event_detail: Detail)

 json.extract[Event]
```

I've read json4s documentation, and also http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.util.parsing.json.JSON$, but still don't quite get it, as it seems the pre-defined json should be fit for the parser?

Could anyone please tell me how to get the second level data (or any lower level) of the json structure?

Comment: This JSON API is deprecated better to use a dedicated&up-to-date JSON lib.

Comment: Why not `case class Wrapper(index_key: Event)`?

Comment: oh...you are right...I can definately use a wapper class, thanks a lot Rex. but I just want to know what if I just want to parse out the inner content of a json string?  @RexKerr

Comment: I'll use json4s, thanks for the heads up @cchantep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\` to get to the object you want to extract:

```
val json = parse(str) \ "index_key"
json.extract[Event]
```

Comment: hi @bjfletcher, just another quick scala question, how to get the "index_key" as a variable? I'm trying to make it a generic json format and parse out all the inner content but the "index_key" could be some other names like "index_key2", "index_key3". thank you so much :P

Comment: `parse(str).as[JsObject].values.head` :)

Comment: "<console>:26: error: not found: type JsObject" and "error: No JSON deserializer found for type <error>. Try to implement an implicit Reader or JsonFormat for this type." at parse(str).as[JsObject].

Comment: I googled a bit and find the "Play framework" should be installed? I'm now only using json4s in console mode. thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, some Play JSON questions flying about and I had forgotten that this was json4s! :) json4s version: `parse(str).as[JObject].children.head`

Comment: Hi @bjfletcher, sorry to bother you again, I'm really new to scala stuff and tried to search but cannot solve it. I ran "parse(str).as[JObject].children.head", and get "error: No JSON deserializer found for type org.json4s.JObject. Try to implement an implicit Reader or JsonFormat for this type." what does this mean? no useful got after google search lol

Comment: `JValue` has `children` so there's no need for the `as[JObject]`. You can use this instead: `parse(str).children.head`

Comment: I want to get the first node key, not the json content of the first node? then I can define"val firstNodeKey = 'index_key' ". thanks a lot

Comment: `parse(str).asInstanceOf[JObject].values.head._1` (and _2 has the value)